# Does casting Web interrupt the spell Sanctuary?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does casting [*web*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web) interrupt the spell [*sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) on the caster? If yes, in which moment? Let us consider the case in which there is an enemy creature in the area covered by the web.

Maybe it can be useful underline a couple of things:

1. When *web* is cast, no creatures are affected.
2. A creature will be affected by the web if it is starting/going through its turn there and fails the saving throw.
3. About *sanctuary*: if the warded creature makes an attack or casts a spell that affects an enemy creature, this spell ends.

Comment: Similar to [How do the Spirit Guardian and Sanctuary spells interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58059/how-do-the-spirit-guardian-and-sanctuary-spells-interact)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## It depends.

The condition for the [*sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spell to end is:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an
> enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

#### Scenario 1: Casting *web* on an unoccupied area

*Sanctuary* would not end, as there are no creatures affected **at the time of casting.** Creatures affected by the spell's ongoing effects after it was cast would not break *sanctuary*, since that is not the condition to break *sanctuary*.

#### Scenario 2: Casting *web* on an occupied area

*Sanctuary* would break **regardless of whether the creatures passed or failed their saving throw.** Forcing a saving throw affects said creature, thus breaking *sanctuary*.

Comment: we know that the forced save is not done at the time of casting, so, following your reasoning, also in scenario 2 Sanctuary is not broken

Comment: It's just "a spell that affects an enemy creature", not "a spell that affects an enemy creature in the moment of casting".

Comment: @enkryptor by that reasoning, Sanctuary would also end if a creature chooses to enter the Webbed area.

Comment: The [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) updated the spell description to include the criterion "deals damage to another creature" as something that ends the spell, though it doesn't affect the answer to this question. You may want to update the quote in your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

## As soon as Web forces a Save, Sanctuary ends.

The [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) say

> If the warded creature [...] casts a spell that affects an enemy creature, [...] this spell ends.

Nothing specifies that the spell must affect creatures at the moment it is cast. So, you cast [Web](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/web) on an area with an enemy Orc in there. The Orc wasn't affected yet (it's not its turn), so Sanctuary is up. Then a few turns go by during which your allies or other enemies move and act, and Sanctuary is up. Then it's the Orc's turn, at the beginning of which he must make a save against the Web spell, and Sanctuary ends at that point.

The idea of Sanctuary (it's even been errata'd to better convey it) is to ensure that you are a sort-of peacekeeper. Enemies have trouble attacking you, but you also cannot be harmful to them.

Answer (score -5):

### *Web* doesn’t affect *sanctuary*

The description of the [*sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) spell says:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, **casts a spell** that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

Casting a *web* spell does not affect anyone. Creatures are affected subsequently by the webs it creates, but that is not the warded creature casting a spell.

Comment: The [2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) updated the spell description to include the criterion "deals damage to another creature" as something that ends the spell, though it doesn't affect the answer to this question. You may want to update the quote in your answer accordingly.