# Does casting Fog Cloud break a Sanctuary spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell [Sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) can ward a creature, with the following caveat:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

Does casting Fog Cloud break a Sanctuary spell?

Arguably, it does not, as the spell affects the air around the enemies, not the enemies themselves.

Comment: Also related: [How do the Spirit Guardian and Sanctuary spells interact?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58059/14878) and [various other questions asking about how spells interact with Sanctuary](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D+sanctuary).

Comment: The related question (that this question was previously closed as a duplicate of): [Does casting Web interrupt the spell Sanctuary?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120472/does-casting-web-interrupt-the-spell-sanctuary)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## *Fog cloud* does not end *sanctuary*

[*Sanctuary*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) states:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, **casts a spell that affects an enemy**, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

[*Fog could*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) states:

> You create a 20-foot-radius sphere of fog centered on a point within range. The sphere spreads around corners, and **its area is heavily obscured**. It lasts for the duration or until a wind of moderate or greater speed (at least 10 miles per hour) disperses it.

**At no point does *fog cloud* affect a creature**, it only affects the area which becomes heavily obscured. Hence, *fog cloud* does not end *sanctuary*.

A [heavily obscured area](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/adventuring#VisionandLight) states:

> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--blocks vision entirely. A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.

However, the blinded condition is not an effect of *fog cloud*, it's the normal interaction between a creature and the environment.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, if there are enemies in the area of effect. No, if there aren't

If there is an enemy in the area of effect of the *Fog Cloud* then it is "a spell that affects an enemy" and *Sanctuary* ends. If there are no enemies in the area then it isn't and it doesn't.

Note that the phrase uses the present tense - if I cast *Fog Cloud* affecting no enemies and an enemy moves into it subsequently, that doesn't end the *Sanctuary*.

Comment: -1: "affect" isn't strictly defined as a game rule. As [Ruse's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/162351/12478) point out, the spell effect only set an area heavily obscured, it technically doesn't do anything to the creatures in it. If we consider your reading correct, I would argue that even if an enemy is outside of the fog when cast, the spell still affect them : the spell reduce their chance to hit targets inside the fog.
Some sources to back up your answer would be nice.