Homebrew Review: Cleric of Night
There are no cleric domains that specifically engage with the dark and the night.
I love the Twilight domain, but I am interested in playing a character whose religion is more in line with a worshiper of Mother Dark from Steven Erikson's Malazan books or a priest of the God of the First Night from Robert Jackson Bennett's City of Miracles. Both of these Gods are inspirations for the subclass below and have portfolios that engage with the night / dark (not to be confused with the half-dark of "shadow") and the way humans deal with the dark and the unknown. They are both somewhat like elemental forces and less like demons—Mother Dark in particular is not evil.
This subclass attempts to fill this role. It is a night-themed cleric domain that is about the elemental concept of darkness rather than the kind of darkness you find in hearts and souls.
I'm looking for possible balance issues, particularly with the 2nd and 6th level features.
I'm likely to be playing a character of this class in an upcoming campaign, and my main concern is that I have overlooked a way in which it will be un-fun to play. I don't intend to abuse the class, but I'm still interested in hearing about abusable mechanics I've overlooked. I've included inline comments on my questions/thoughts throughout.
Subclass Description

Domain of Night
You are a cleric of a God whose portfolio touches upon the elemental forces of the Dark and the Night. Although the Dark is often favored by evil gods and gods associated with deceit, many gods—of the moon, the forest, or sleep, for example—might offer their worshipers the obscuring and protective power of the Night Domain.
Pupil of the Dusk
1st-level Night Domain feature
You have become a pupil of the Dusk, granting you an affinity for darkness and stealth. You gain domain spells at the cleric levels listed in the Night Domain Spells table. See the Divine Domain class feature for how domain spells work.
Additionally, you gain proficiency in Stealth, and you gain darkvision to a range of 120 feet. Within this range, you can see in both normal and magical darkness.

Proficiency in Stealth and one eldritch invocation (Devil's Sight) seem fairly modest in terms of power compared to the level 1 features of other cleric domains. The ability to see through magical darkness isn't typically a cleric thing, but since Devil's Sight can be obtained by a feat, this seems uncontroversial; possibly a little weak overall.
This is intended to be a caster cleric so no heavy armor or martial weapons.

Night Domain Spells



Cleric Level
Spells




1st
bane, sleep


3rd
darkness, invisibility


5th
fear, dispel magic


7th
death ward, greater invisibility


9th
passwall, dream




I don't suspect that there are serious balance or fun issues here. All of these spells appear on similar lists (cleric domains or land druid spell lists) with the exception of fear. Fear is a powerful spell, but I doubt it unbalances the list on its own.

Channel Divinity: Uncover the Dark
2nd-level Night Domain feature
Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to harness the Dark, banishing light and concealing your allies.
As an action, you present your holy symbol, and any magical illumination of your choice within 30 feet of you is dispelled. Following this, you and a number of creatures of your choice up to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of 1) within 30 feet of you that you can see become invisible until the start of your next turn. The effect ends early for a creature immediately after it makes an attack or casts a spell.

I don't know of another ability that let's you do something quite like this, so I'm not completely sure how to think about its power-level. Being able to make up to 5 creatures plus yourself invisible usually takes a level-7 spell slot, but that lasts an hour and this lasts a round. This is closer to granting 5 creatures a 1-round advantage on their next attack, which seems fairly reasonable compared to some of the better channel divinity abilities like Twilight Sanctuary.

Veil of Midnight
6th-level Night Domain feature
You have learned how to craft the Night into a veil of shifting darkness that can protect your allies. As a reaction whenever a creature you can see within 30 feet of you ends its turn, you may grant them a number of temporary hit points equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of 1) and the effects of the sanctuary spell. The Night grants you the ability to perceive the moment that corresponds to the end of a creature's turn for this purpose. You may do this a number of times equal to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of 1) and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Clerics don't usually have very good reactions, so giving a reaction, even a weak one, is still a nice bonus with respect to the action economy. In my experience, Sanctuary is a nice effect to get, especially at the end of one's turn, but it's also not usually a game-changer because it only works against attacks, it usually only lasts a round, and you often still have a reasonable chance of getting hit. The temporary hit points make this just a little better.
Power-wise, the Twilight domain offers a fairly high watermark for comparison with the Steps of Night feature. It lets a cleric grant themselves 1 minute of flight, proficiency bonus (PB) times per day. The flight they get is clearly not as good as the Fly spell, so I think of this as being like PB free casts of a spell each day that's approximately level-2. This grants Wisdom modifier free casts of a spell that's somewhat better than a level-1 spell, which seems about right.

Potent Spellcasting
8th-level Night Domain feature
Starting at 8th level, you add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any cleric cantrip.

This is a caster subclass, so it follows the Potent Spellcasting pattern.

Crafts of the Witching Hour
17th-level Night Domain feature
When you cast the Darkness spell, its area of effect is increased to a 30 foot sphere, and you may form the darkness into any shape that fits within the spell's area of effect. Additionally, while you are concentrating on the Darkness spell, you may use a bonus action to move the spell to a new location within 60 feet of you and reshape it (as if you had cast the spell anew). This bonus action does not change the duration of the spell.

This ability is unlikely to see much play, but that said, I wanted it to be interesting both for combat and for role-play. Combat-wise, this saves you from having to recast darkness and allows you to place just your foes in darkness while sparing your allies. I think it would give the cleric a lot of control over battlefield tactics without changing too much in terms of raw power. For role-play, you can have the night literally follow you through doors and corridors, up and down stairways. You can put shadows in corners or make dark figures that move around. There's really nothing like shadow-puppet magic in the 5e ruleset, and this feature fixes that.

Veil of Midnight needs a little tweaking. "a creature ends its turn" is not an appropriate reaction trigger -- "when a creature is targeted with an attack or harmful spell" would be in line with the wording of Sanctuary.

@DwayneTheVrock I don't understand how either choice of wording is in line with the wording of Sanctuary, or why the feature would need to be? What is the problem you are proposing to fix with your comment?

@DwayneTheVrock I came across this question/answer, which is maybe what you are referring to: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48139/73324
I added some text to the feature that should clarify, thanks for the suggestion.
The Night grants you the ability to perceive the moment that corresponds to the end of a creature's turn for this purpose.

I am unable to review it, but I appreciate the quality of writing and the effort you show here, explaining why and what. This is a perfect example of good subclass homebrew review, and if you won't get answers, I'll put a bounty on it.

@Mołot Thanks for the kind words!

This might be just slightly overpowered
Overall, I think this is pretty well balanced. I think there are some things which may have some problems, but there's some really good flavor in here that I think may make it so the player doesn't really care.
When looking at this, I compared against a few other cleric domains, specifically Arcana, Light, Trickery, Twilight, and War.
Pupil of the Dusk
Overall, I think this feature is really good. 120' darkvision coupled with the ability to see through magical darkness is nothing to sneeze at. As you noted, such a thing could be obtained by taking a feat (notably that specific feat is pretty good), but this is doing even more than that as it's also granting proficiency in Stealth.
When reviewing the other domains, I noted that granting skill proficiencies was generally a rare thing, reserving it for thematically appropriate situations (i.e. Arcana proficiency for the Arcana Domain).
This feature is definitely very strong, but I don't think the fact that it's really good makes it busted. There's a lot of domains which various builds would want to make a 1 level dip for what it grants them and I think this domain isn't any different. Of the domains I compared against, the only one which I struggled to see a character build that included a 1 level dip was the Arcana Domain Cleric, but I think that's because it's kind of a weak domain overall that needs a specific kind of campaign to function well in.
Domain Spells
Honestly, these all looked fine, but I wasn't clear on why you chose Passwall.
Channel Divinity: Uncover the Dark
This seems like you've flipped half of the Light Domain's feature and for the other half gave a short-term invisibility effect. Overall, I think the invisibility effect is pretty strong and is also pretty versatile as it does allow your allies to escape as well.
Because the effect is good and relatively universally useful, I think you can expect to use it most every adventuring day.
I'm questioning whether it's overpowered, though, because the Trickery domain's 6th level feature is to turn the cleric invisible until the end of their next turn. In general, this is giving everyone Advantage on their attacks and all enemies Disadvantage, while also letting everyone reposition without triggering AoO. I think to make it more fair you should rephrase it as follows:

As an action, you present your holy symbol, and any magical illumination of your choice within 30 feet of you is dispelled. Following this, you pick a number of creatures of your choice up to your Wisdom modifier (minimum of 1) within 30 feet of you that you can see become invisible until the start of your next turn. The effect ends early for a creature immediately after it makes an attack or casts a spell or if you lose concentration (as if you were concentrating on a spell).

It's not obvious, but I modified the language in the 2nd sentence to make it so turning yourself invisible wasn't a default option.
This change lets you use this powerful feature, but to do so you need to drop any control spells that you currently have going.
Veil of Midnight
I don't think you need the additional language regarding knowing when a creature ends it's turn. I know you added it responding to a comment, but there are several published features that trigger off that (Twilight Sanctuary, Wall of Fire, etc).
Overall, this feature's goals don't seem unbalanced and keeping in theme with the 2nd level feature, which is to disincentivize enemies attacking your allies. The Light Domain does this by imposing Disadvantage on an enemy's single attack roll, this doesn't exactly do the same thing since the enemy could pick a different target or use an AoE instead.
Overall, I think it's fine. It's possible that you might need to up the amount of temp HP, but I think that's something you have to see in play test with consideration that there's a lot of action economy in this reaction [Bonus Action spell (Sanctuary) and an Action spell (False Life]. This makes the ally safe, on your next turn you can get close and use an Action to drop a high level Cure Wounds to fix them up.
Potent Spellcasting
Yeah, it's fine.
Crafts of the Witching Hour
I think this feature's fine as well, but I am a little concerned on how to adjudicate this at the table. You may want to more thoroughly describe how the shadows can be shaped (i.e. similar to Wall of Stone rules or can things be disconnected).
Overall, the feature itself is very powerful, but generally all the 17th level Cleric features are. However, at this level, most of the enemies you'll be facing can readily avoid the worst of this feature by just moving.
Cezaryx's answer made a very good point regarding this feature that the enemies you'll face at this level just aren't really going to be negatively impacted by Darkness, which does effectively completely negate the usefulness of this feature. I would recommend consider amending the feature in some fashion to improve it's functionality, here's some ideas:

Make it so that your allies can see through the darkness as well.
Include some statement that the darkness is disrupts blind sight and true sight.
Maybe allow the darkness to be shaped and be tangible in a fashion similar to an Illusionist Wizard's Illusory Reality feature. This would be a bit of callback to 3.5's shadow spells like Shadow Conjuration.


Thanks for this analysis! This is all very useful, and it feels like you understood all the pieces clearly; the comments on the level-2 feature are very insightful in particular.
Agreed that Passwall is a weird fit, but there aren't great thematic fits at level-5 (Mislead maybe? or Cone of Cold?).
I did some playtesting last night and agree 100% that the L17 ability is tricky at the table—I had to track an irregular checkerboard of dark/light squares changing each round. Could be limited to a sphere/cylinder/cube or the shape of an object/creature with which the cleric is familiar.

@Pyrotechnical I just want to add to your take on additional wording for Veil of Midnight. While other features gives benefits at the end of someones turn, the difference here is that it is an reaction, and end of turn is established as not suitable trigger for reaction since characters in game cannot perceive it, that's why i believe additional text is a good addition to trigger condition.

@nben When I was looking through the 5th level spell list, I suspected that lack of appropriate thematic spells was the issue. Like you, I also felt like Mislead was the only one I could identify that made some kind of sense.

@ArekKubiński I see what you mean, the lack of discernible trigger is the issue.

I'm going to think on this and see if I can come up with some better phrasing.

@ArekKubiński The rule that mentions the trigger has to be perceivable concerns Readied Actions. Additionally, specific beats general, so if a spell or feature specifies that you can take a reaction at the end of someone's turn, you can. Look at the scout rogue's Skirmisher feature "You can move up to half your speed as a reaction when an enemy ends its turn within 5 feet of you".

@HoneyBattery that's a great point, thank you for finding it.

@nben per HoneyBattery's point, I'm going to pass on revised phrasing for Midnight Veil and just encourage you to omit the excess language. Though I did incorporate some discussion on the boons of it with regards to action economy.

It's a-okay-to-play, if not lacking in some areas, definitely not strong
I don't think you would have any problems with playing/allowing play with this subclass, though I don't think this is good as presented, at least in some places. It has some feelbad features. Will it break a game - certainly not. Will it be fun to play - in my honest opinion, debatable. To sum up: as a primary spellcaster, cleric will find use for some domain spells here, that fill the gaps usually found within cleric spellist, but the features, while usable, are not jaw dropping in any quality whatsoever, and using some is straight up bad, so it's mostly spells for this cleric. To the features:

Pupil of the Dusk
Superior Darkvision as well as one, non-changeable skill proficiency is a ribbon feature, so two together are two ribbons. Thanks to seeing through magical darkness this is barely a usable feature as a sum of its part, though if you won't go out of your way to use that magical darkness vision, you probably won't be using it often, if at all, almost certainly not till 3rd level whan you can actually capitalize on it, so it's so so all things considered. And to bear in mind, if you won't build around that with your entire team, then you are just making things worse for your teammates.

Night Domain Spells
Sleep and fear are the outliers here, they give cleric good control, though sleep is short-lived, and both invisibilities a utility and nice buff that was not present on cleric spell list normally. The rest are cleric spells, so nothing of note, or circumstantial stuff, so nothing outstanding. All in all, a good spell list, not great one.

Channel Divinity: Uncover the Dark
Thanks to the invisibility this is better than insanely circumstantial use that are worth very little, and even then it's not jaw dropping. It's nice to have, and can be useful, but this is not overtuned by any means. As for dispelling magical light - I find it hilarious this will snuff out an artifical star held in wizard's hand created by Wish spell, but it won't snuff out a torch, or a candle. Really? You could went with the theme till the end here, why non-magical lights are unaffected is beyond me. As for actual usage of this - I think it may come up once in a campaign, maybe not, so it's okay.
Veil of Midnight

This is very weak, 4 temp hit points as a reaction when you get this, 16 total for a long rest, for max 5 and 25? Second level warlock can have much more, any first level character with a feat can generate more per long rest, either for themselves or for others, this is nothing. Thank god you are a cleric and have no good reaction spells or reactions overall, so you could actually use this sometimes. But if you are a race with some reaction (any race, none has worse than this), or better, have access to shield or silvery barbs from somewhere, then you have infinitely better usage of your reaction than this feature, and more reliable. Yes, this is additional and does not use any of your resources, but it's not much at 6th level, and never after will be.
Then there is the topic of sanctuary spell. So, in short:

it's good this is at the end of the turn, as to not waste the effect on someone that will act next

90% of times or more it won't last longer than one round, sometimes less than that

if enemy has any form of AoE, it is nothing


Sanctuary is not a good spell, it's not a waste of resources only if cast on PC that is 100% focused on doing everything except damage and control, so rarely anyone. And now is 6th level, so a spell not particularly useful on 1st level is even worse. And you cannot prep it after the rest and forget about it before any first combat that day, like the temp hit points part, because it lasts for only a minute and is not connected to temp hit points part in any way.
Together it is passable, but in my opinion just weak overall.
Potent Spellcasting

Nothing out of the ordinary, nothing to talk about.
Crafts of the Witching Hour

Very nice buff to the darkness spell. And I also fail to imagine why on 17th level would you ever consider to cast it. Are you sure enemies have no senses that go around it(and most of them do on this level of play), so it's pointless to use?  Are you sure you won't murder the wizard's ability to blast enemies with his spells, for they need a line of sight for them, which you do not automatically grant them? Are you sure others won't be worse for you using it too?  And even then, are you sure there is no better use of your concentration, like that greater invisibility you got from your domain spells, or any spell of 6th level and higher you have as a full spellcaster? My man, this makes the spell better, and by encouraging its use at 17th level instead of the things that just are massively more on-point, makes the entire class' performance worse. Sorry to say, but beside some extremely circumstantial usage (so much so I cannot make one up on the spot to justify it) it's a bad feature, and a feelsbad one too.

With regards to the Veil of Midnight, I feel like you might be overestimating the occasional need to remove the amount of aggro an ally has drawn. Given this is intending to be casting cleric, it's reasonable to assume a relatively strong save DC which can definitely disincentivize a brute type enemy from piling on damage on a wounded ally. This then gives the ally time to receive healing, get into a better position, and attack on better terms. Given that combats are usually short (3-5 rounds), having 1 round of breathing can be a big deal. I do concur with your point on the amount of temp HP.

Also Veil of Midnight can be a very good choice for an arcane caster whom is focusing their efforts on buffing allies and using control spells. This might depend upon how the DM rules regarding how Sanctuary works and what breaks the effect (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162340/31402) (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120472/31402).

you might be underestimating the occasional need*

@nben I think there's a really good point here regarding the Crafts of the Witching Hour that I overlooked in my answer. Just in the basic rules, almost every enemy of CR15 or higher has some means of completely negating the effects of Darkness, so this might just serve to make things harder for your allies.

@Pyrotechnical Magical darkness? The darkness spell is opaque to entities with darkvision, so one would need Devil's Sight or blindsight to see through it. (That said, I don't know the CR15 enemies well.)

@nben almost every enemy from CR15-20 in the basic rules has either Blindsight or Truesight.

@Pyrotechnical Iron Golem? Mummy Lord? Haha, apparently, the list I found is full of unofficial content. Thanks for checking.

@Cezaryx There are some useful observations in this review, but the whole answer would be much improved for me if you backed up your many opinions with actual facts/data/comparisons. Case in point, for the L17 ability, you ask four kinda sarcastic questions that helped me not at all until Pyrotechnical looked up the high-CR monster senses and translated into an actual piece of useful information. Or: without knowing what kind of table you play at I don't know what to make of your analysis that a couple features "aren't jaw dropping"—that sounds like "are balanced" to me.

On Pupil of Dusk, I see what you're saying in regards to having to wait for the feature to 'fully come online', however, I would note that this is also true for Warlocks using a Devil's Sight build. At 2nd level, they take the invocation, but they still have to wait until 3rd level for them to gain the Darkness spell. But I think you're underestimating a free skill proficiency in Stealth; first that's a pretty good one to have and second clerics don't really get a lot of skills so this plugs a hole for some builds.

One final note on Midnight Veil, this is letting a cleric effectively use the spell effects of both an Action (False Life) and a Bonus Action (Sanctuary). That is very good action economy.
