# Does a Counterspelled spell break Sanctuary?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, counterspelling

Let's say I've cast *Hold Person* on an enemy while protected by Sanctuary. Enemy *Counterspell*s, making the save for my Sanctuary and successfully countering my spell. Does this break my Sanctuary?

For reference:
[Sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary) (emphasis mine):

> You ward a creature within range against attack. Until the spell ends, any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack or a harmful spell must first make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or lose the attack or spell. This spell doesn't protect the warded creature from area effects, such as the explosion of a fireball.

> **If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.**

[Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) (emphasis mine):

> You attempt to interrupt a creature in the process of casting a spell. **If the creature is casting a spell of 3rd level or lower, its spell fails and has no effect.** If it is casting a spell of 4th level or higher, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a success, the creature's spell fails and has no effect

Answer (score 27):

#### Your *Sanctuary* spell ended just as you started casting *Hold Person*.

The enemy did not have to make the Wisdom saving throw, because *Hold Person* is a spell that *affects* an enemy and then one of the ending requirements for *Sanctuary* is met:

> If the warded creature makes an attack, **casts a spell that affects an enemy**, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

Hence, enemy's *Counterspell* has no role in ending your *Sanctuary* spell.

---

For the interpretation of "*casts a spell that affects an enemy*", see [When a spell is cast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141300/63061) and the [Sage Advice Compendium clarification](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA264) about concentration spells.

Comment: While I believe this answer to be correct, can you defend the assumption that Hold Person is considered to be cast for the purposes of Sanctuary at the _beginning_ of casting and not the _end_ (since Counterspell specifically happens between the two)?

Comment: The OP seems to belive that Sanctuary is still active during Counterspell because Hold Person hasn't completed yet (i.e. Santuary ends when the spell _completes_ casting). Eddymage says Sanctuary ends right when you decide to cast Hold Person (i.e. Sanctuary ends when the spell _starts_ casting). Concentration rules would be a good precedent towards the second line of reasoning.

Comment: You can also refeence [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141300/38834) which is specifically about "when is a spell considered cast".. Hint: It's when you start.

Comment: @smbailey I was thinking to add the the rules and the SAC about concentration, but I think that Kirt and MivaScott found a better explanation: I am adding this bit to the answer.

Comment: However, Sage Advice Compendium says (WRT Slow) that a spell's target is only selected at the end of its casting. Which would suggest that the character is only affected when the spell is finished casting, while Counterspell is cast while the spell is being cast.

Comment: @JarnoPorkka You are casting a spell that affects an enemy, but it does not matter _which_ enemy. *Counterspell* here has no role at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145596/discussion-between-eddymage-and-jarno-porkka).

Answer (score 8):

## What kind of spell are we talking about?

### Spell-as-kind *vs.* spell-as-instance

*[Sanctuary](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sanctuary)* says

> If the warded creature makes an attack, casts a spell that affects an enemy, or deals damage to another creature, this spell ends.

The question here is what does "casts a spell that affects an enemy" mean.  It *could* mean 'casts a spell of the kind of spells that affect enemies', or it *could* mean 'casts a spell that does result in affecting an enemy'.  That is, are we looking at the *general kind* of the spell-as-category or at the *specific effect* of the spell-as-instance?  It is precisely this distinction that is argued in the related question [Sanctuary + readied spell that affects an enemy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202277/23547).

#### RAW, the text is ambiguous

Unfortunately, the phrase "that affects an enemy" does not appear anywhere else in the PHB.  With nothing to compare it to, the best we can say RAW is that it is the DM's call as far as what kind of spell *Sanctuary* is referring to.  If *Sanctuary* would be ended by the general kind of spells that affect enemies, then since *Hold Person* is the *kind* of spell that affects enemies, *sanctuary* is immediately ended as soon as the *Hold Person* spell is started.  If, on the other hand, *Sanctuary* would be ended by a specific instance of a spell that *does* affect an enemy (as Thomas Markov agues in [his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202278/23547)), then *sanctuary* is not ended because this particular instance of *Hold Person* did not affect an enemy (since it was *Counterspelled* before it could have an effect).

#### If we extrapolate from similar wording, it is likely spell-as-kind

In the aforementioned question, Exempt-Medic's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202280/23547) points out that although we do not have another example of "that affects an enemy", the phrase is worded similarly to Overchannel<sup>1</sup>, which says "When you cast a wizard spell...that deals damage".  It makes more sense for Overchannel's ability to refer to a general *kind* of spells, rather than a specific instance of casting.  For example, if the evoker wishes to Overchannel *scorching ray*, it should be sufficient to say '*scorching ray* is the *kind* of spell that deals damage, thus you can Overchannel it'.  The alternative, that you can only Overchannel a spell that actually does damage, means telling the wizard 'You have to roll to hit first, because we won't know whether or not you can Overchannel until you actually do damage, since if you miss with all the attacks Overchannel won't work'.

#### This DM would choose the convenience of spell-as-kind

We need to be careful of making analogies about a different phrasing, but the Overchannel example, to me, suggests the utility in ruling that *Sanctuary* is referring to the general kind of the spell, not the specific instance.  Indeed, thinking about 'what if all the *rays* miss?', makes it more clear to me that the spirit of *Sanctuary* is about intent, not result.  As a GM, I certainly don't want the headache of players trying to game *sanctuary* by making arguments like 'they made their save against *sacred flame* so I didn't affect an enemy, my *sanctuary* is still up', or 'sure, I cast *web*, but [that doesn't affect the enemy until their next turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/120472/23547), so I didn't affect an enemy when I cast the spell and my *sanctuary* is still up'.  I don't want players trying to cast potentially harmful spells and then retaining their *sanctuary* if the spell fails.

In the aforementioned question, Groody the Hobgoblin's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202279/23547) gives the example that a caster could lay down a *black tentacles* on an area without immediately losing the *sanctuary* under the spell-as-instance interpretation, but also says that the caster would then lose the *sanctuary* later, when the *tentacles* did damage.  This brings in the issue of timing; must the enemy be affected 'when you cast'?  Does *sanctuary* end 'If you cast a spell that does affect an enemy at the moment of casting?' or does it end 'If you cast a spell that does affect an enemy, when that enemy is affected'?  This is another reason to avoid the interpretation of spell-as-instance; by ruling that *sanctuary* only cares about the kind of spell you are casting, it is simpler to resolve and you don't have to wait and find out what the spell actually does later.  I have to admit I am biased towards rulings that simplify my decisions as a DM rather than those that create even more edge cases.

#### A JC tweet can be interpreted as spell-as-instance

Jeremy Crawford [was once asked](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/758741709064773632) about another way to game *sanctuary* - a cleric casting *spirit guardians* on themselves, then *sanctuary* and wading into combat, using the *spirit guardians* offensively but retaining *sanctuary* (and see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58059/23547)).

His response was that, as *sanctuary* was then written, this exploit was allowed.  However, the intent was that "a damaging activity ends the spell".  Note that he wrote this tweet in 2016, when *sanctuary* did not have its 'or the caster deals damage to another creature' clause, since that was added in a 2018 errata.  Thus at one level he is just saying what the errata adds - that causing damage to a creature is another end condition for sanctuary.  But considering the question he is responding to, we may conclude that he is looking at this as spell-as-instance; he says one may cast *spirit guardians* without dropping *sanctuary* because it does not matter that spirit guardians is the *kind* of spell that affects enemies.  The spell only becomes an end condition later, at the point in time that *spirit guardians* actually does damage.  Thus for JC, RAI is spell-as-instance rather than spell-as-kind.

#### Conclusion

The RAW for *sanctuary* are ambiguous and thus open to DM interpretation. This DM thinks it is less problematic to assume the 'spell-as-general class' interpretation, but there is certainly support for the opposing view.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Exempt-Medic also gives helpful examples of other, similarly worded, spells.</sub>

Comment: Groody's answer is dependent on that example, but that example targets an area, not a creature. Applying it to creature-targeting is very different and I don't think a parallel.

Comment: @NautArch Sanctuary doesn't say it ends when the caster 'targets' an enemy, though, just 'affects'.  So a spell that targets an area but affects an enemy should end it just as much as one that targets an enemy and affects that same enemy.

Comment: Using this logic, casting Hold Person on an ally for their benefit (to prevent their fleeing into a more dangerous area, say) would end Sanctuary.  That interpretation seems questionable to me at best.

Comment: Would throwing a fireball onto an area definitely known to be empty of enemies end Sanctuary too? Let's say that the creature warded by Sanctuary is doing that for fun (alternatively, maybe the creature warded by Sanctuary is affected by Suggestion)

Comment: @Spitemaster That is a good point, if all that sanctuary cared about was the class of spell.  But under either interpretation, sanctuary somehow knows who is an enemy and who isn't.  So perhaps a more precise wording would be 'casts a spell of the kind that affects enemies with the intent of affecting an enemy'.

Comment: @justhalf Would throwing a fireball onto an area thought to be clear of creatures and accidently damaging an allied but hidden rogue end sanctuary?  Somehow sanctuary knows what an enemy is, so it must take intent into account in some way.

Comment: @Kirt Based on the sage advice for Twinned Spell, there is little to no difference between "target" and "affect". Creatures affected by an AOE are considered "targets" of the spell.

Comment: @Wlerin I agree, but don't think that affects my answer?  Or was your comment more directed at NautArch's [comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205897/does-a-counterspelled-spell-break-sanctuary/205906?noredirect=1#comment564396_205906)?

Comment: It was directed at that chain of comments, yes. And you're correct it doesn't affect your answer.